# Customizing apache directory listing ONLY for subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, directory

I have a Download folder where I set up a directory listing sorted by last modified date, like this :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/Downloads/>
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>
```

I want to keep this folder sorted by date, but have all its sub-directories (recursively) sorted by name. Is it possible ?

I tried this and it didn't work :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/Downloads/>
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>
<Directory /home/Download/*/*>
            IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name
</Directory>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you mean the folder `/var/www/html/Downloads/` and all subfolders of `/home/Download/` OR the folder `/var/www/html/Downloads/` and all its subfolders.

`/var/www/html/Downloads/` and all its subfolders:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/Downloads/>
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/Downloads/(.+)/">
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name
</DirectoryMatch>
```

If there is no misspelling in `/home/Download/`, try:

```
<Directory /home/Download/*/>
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved my problem by using JS on the listing page to add "?C=N;O=A" at the end of all the links.